# C# EF Linq Create a list based on another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm not sure if the title accurately describes this situation, but I'm trying!

I have a list of Project objects that have a Category value and I basically want to "invert" the list to make it a distinct list of categories that exist within the projects and the projects that belong to them.

So, instead of:

```
Project1
     -> Category1
Project2
     -> Category2
Project3
     -> Category1
```

I want:

```
Category1
     -> Project1
     -> Project3
Category2
     -> Project2
```

Currently I'm doing 2 linq statements, the first grabbing the distinct categories and the second selecting the projects with the specific category and creating a new list with an object with Category and Projects (list of projects) properties.

I know that I'll need to create a class for the Category/Projects object because of EF, but wondering if I can build the list with one statement instead of two?

Thanks!

Here's the code that I use currently

```
// This just pulls the unique categories belonging to the projects
string[] categories = dbm.GetProjectCategories().ToArray();
foreach(string category in categories)
{
     // This pulls the projects with the specific category
     Project[] projects = dbm.GetProjects(category).ToArray();
     // New object with the specific category and the projects belonging to it.
     projlst.Add(new CategoryProjectsItem(category, projects));
}
```

I know it'll be a bit different using EF instead of straight ADO.NET.

These pull from the same table of projects.

Comment: Can you put your current code?

Answer (score 1):

I poked around more, and figured it out!
Here's a simplified example:

**CategoryProjectsItem**

```
public class CategoryProjectsItem
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

**Within my method to pull the inverted list**

```
var rlt = await db.Projects2.GroupBy(c => c.Category)
                .Select(p => new CategoryProjectsItem()
                {
                    Category = p.Key,
                    Projects = p.Select(r => new Project() {
                        ID = r.ID,
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Category = r.Category
                    }).ToList()
                }).ToListAsync();
```